# Convert Grizzly/Jersey to Payara

Tags: java, jersey, migration, grizzly, payara

So, we've built a webapp using Grizzly/Jersey.  You run the produced jar file, and it then provides REST endpoints, which allow pulling data from the database and creating new entries, etc.  For one reason or another, we now want to migrate to a webserver, like Payara or Glassfish or something.  I'm having trouble getting it to work.  It compiles to a war, now, and gets deployed to Payara.  Following [Deploying jersey web services on Payara 4 doesn´t expose methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025458/deploying-jersey-web-services-on-payara-4-doesn%C2%B4t-expose-methods), I got it to at least acknowledge that there are endpoints.  However, they rely on an injected EntityManager, which we define/bind (along with its dependencies) in a ResourceConfig subclass, which isn't getting loaded, so it crashes.  Anybody know how to load the ResourceConfig?  Also, anything else that will need to be done to get this working?

Comment: Did you do what the answer in your linked post says? (Hint: ResourceConfig extends Application).

Comment: You also need to make sure you have the `jersey-container-servlet` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going off the answer from your linked post

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("API_PATH_FOR_JAXRS")
public class SampleApplication extends Application {

}
```

This would explain the behavior you are seeing. An empty `Application` annotated with `@ApplicationPath` will cause the Jersey bootstrap to scan the classpath for `@Path` and `@Provider` class, and register those classes.

But you are using a `ResourceConfig` to do all your registration yourself. It just happens that `ResourceConfig` is actually a subclass of `Application`. So instead of creating a new `Application` subclass to put the `@ApplicationPath` annotation on, just put on your `ResourceConfig` subclass.

If you were not subclassing `ResourceConfig` previously, e.g.

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
    .packages("...")
    .register(...);
```

Then just subclass it now

```
@ApplicationPath("...")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        packages("...");
        register(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't realized that ResourceConfig was a subclass of Application.  Unfortunately, it's still telling me there are unsatisfied dependencies.  In the ResourceConfig's constructor, we register an AbstractBinder, in whose `configure()` function we call `bindFactory()` a few times to set up factories to produce `EntityManager`s.  It works in Grizzly/Jersey, but isn't currently working for Payara; any idea why?  The code does get run when I deploy, but after registering the AbstractBinder it still says "deploy is failing"..."Unsatisfied dependencies for type EntityManager"....

Comment: Add a log in the ResourceConfig constructor. Is it being logged?